# CSS: weird border

Tags: html, css

I`m working on a layout and I have now a problem and I don't know how to fix it:
[image: The problem]

CSS:

```
   #menu {
    background-color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    height:46px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#menu > ul {
    display:inline;
}

#menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:134px;
    height:100%;
    border-bottom-color: #f9f7f7;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 6px;
    border-right-color: #f9f7f7;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    display:table;
}

#menu > ul > li > a {
    text-align:center;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    margin-top:17px;
}

#menu > ul {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#selected {
    border-bottom-color: #9d1624 !IMPORTANT;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RuUkM/

I have tried border-bottom-width:100px but then I get a red 100px height thingy.

How to fix this and why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's perfectly fine, the problem is that you have `display:table`, so you'll need to add `border-collapse:collapse` for the li

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that with before and after pseudo elements

```
#menu > ul > li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

#menu > ul > li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: blue;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/RuUkM/5/

Comment: IE 7 and down don't support the before and after pseudo elements, just so readers are aware.  Lucien got it with one line, `border-collapse:collapse`, and covers more browsers.

Comment: Where is the selected? you should edit your demo to **hightlight** the selected item by underline.

Answer (score 2):

CSS borders are generated using angled corners. when you have a colored border on the bottom, like you do, and a different colored border on the right you will get that angled edge. Here is a diagram:

[image]

Some people take advantage of this to create triangles. But your issue is the same thing, just remove the right border to get a clean edge.

Comment: It looks like he wants the right border for styling purposes.  His issue can be fixed without scrapping the design.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that on the `li`, `border-right` is interfering with `border-bottom`. That is why half of the bottom border is "shifted" 1px to the left:

```
border-right-width: 1px;
```